# How do you print text onto a view in an mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

What function of the CDC class allows you to display a string onto the client area?

This doesn't work:

```
  void CpuzzleView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
 {
  CpuzzleDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
  ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
  if (!pDoc)
    return;

  pDC->Rectangle(50,50,100,100);
  pDC->MoveTo(75,75);
  std::cout << "3";
```

}

Comment: Stop using cout and printfs in Windows GUI applications, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CDC::TextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzabsdzx) or [`CDC::DrawTextEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7dfdzwya.aspx).